# child control larger than parent when width equal

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to resize a custom panel control so that it fits in the parent container width-wise. When I check the controls values they are both the same, yet the child control is too wide for the parent control.

What is causing the difference? I want to be able to calculate the correct size. I tried changing padding and margin options but this didn't have any effect.

[image: Extends too far to the right]

```
[Category("Collapsible Panel")]
[DesignOnly(true)]
[DefaultValue(false)]
[Description("If True, fits the panel to match the parent width")]
public bool FitToParent
{
    get { return _fitToParent; }
    set { 
        _fitToParent = value;
            if (_fitToParent)
            {
                if (this.Parent != null)
                {
                    this.Location = new Point(0, this.Location.Y);
                    this.Size = new Size(this.Parent.Size.Width, this.Size.Height);
                    this.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                this.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Left;
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Work with the `ClientSize` of the forms and controls.

```
control.ClientSize.Width
```

`form.Width` or `control.Width` is the outer width including the borders. The `ClientRectangle` is what is between the borders where other controls can be placed and `ClientSize` is the size of this inner rectangle.